# I am having problems installing any VSIX package into my computer

Tags: visual-studio-2022, vsix, windows-11, intel-oneapi, coderush

Whenever I try to install a VSIX package I get the following error:

```
---------------------------
VSIX Installer
---------------------------
The type initializer for 'PerTypeValues`1' threw an exception.
---------------------------
OK   
-------
```

This happens even when I try to install Intel's OneAPI 2024.0, which tries to install a VSIX package, or when I try to install the DevExpress CodeRush Ultimate VSIX file.

I need these products installed to be able to work.

Basically, I tried every reasonable solution I could find on the Internet, including reinstalling the latest version of VS 2022, removing every other third-party tool I had installed in VS, and temporarily suspending my antivirus program. I also tried repairing Windows system files by running 'SFC /scannow' in the propt command, but to no avail.

I have a Microsoft Laptop 2 and none of these problems occur with it, which makes it very clear that this is a Windows 11 problem on this particular computer.

Is there any way to resolve this issue, or at least try to debug it, other than reinstalling Windows from scratch, which is not a viable option for me?

Thanks for any tips. I really need to resolve this issue as soon as possible.